# How to move an element on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, element

I want to move some elements (divs with images) vertically at different speed. I already achieve this partially with the animate jquery function with anchors. However I couldn't figure it out how to do it with the scroll event. I want the same movement (vertically at different speed) also through the scrolling. The scrolling must have the same effect on the "browser-scroll" and on the "mouse-scroll" (no sure about these names).

```
function scroll() {
    $("#logo").animate({ "top": "+=180px" }, 1000);
$("#logo2").animate({ 'top': "+=450px"}, 1000);
}
```

this is the function that I got.

I made same research and I found some cases but none of them helped me really.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/5HHxK/1/

What is it you want? If you want different speeds, with same "position", just slow the speed :)

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks for your reply! I think that's going to help me get started :). I need to re-think the positioning of my divs (relative vs fixed vs absolute). Now I have 2 questions about your reply. What if I want to scroll up? The squares just scroll down because I put "top": "+=__px" but when I scroll up the increment should be "-=__px". The other question is if I need to specify the height of the content (100000px in this case that you posted). What happens in different browsers and when I'm trying to resize the window? Sorry if those are basic questions but I'm a begginer :)

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/5HHxK/5/ .... And no, i just did that for the scrollbar to actually appear (you cant scroll without scrollbar) :) What are you trying to achieve? If its just a fixed menu, you could use something like this plugin this http://jsfiddle.net/5HHxK/

Comment: Marco the first link that you posted was one of my problems! Excellent! I though that I needed to get the position of the scroll but I wasn't getting there. Thanks! The second question: I asked you that because I want to allow scroll only after a event (a drag and drop event). Before that I'd like to prevent user to scroll (I don't  know if I'm explaining myself properly). What I'm trying to achieve is something like: a page with a menu (navigate between div) and to allow the user to scroll between them as well. This scroll moves elements (images) at different speed. Once again thank you Marco